# Need to delay the item changed signal till my data is loaded

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm loading a mysql database on a tablewidget.

I have two functions which are connected to the item changed signal in the my QTable Widget. The first makes a list of the changed cells while the second is used to manage the data types input in the table widget cells bringing up an error message if the wrong datatype is put in.

The problem is that the functions work before I load my database in. Effectively storing a list of cells I don't want and popping continuous error messages while it is loading.

How do I halt the functions working till after the database is loaded?

```
def log_change(self, item):
    self.changed_items.append([item.row(),item.column()])


def item_changed(self, Qitem,item):
    if (item.column())%2 == 0:
        try:
            test = float(Qitem.text())
        except ValueError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error, value must be number!")
            Msgbox.exec()
            Qitem.setText(str(''))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- Use a flag:

```
    # in constructor
    self.is_loading = False

def load_from_db(self):
    # in load function
    self.is_loading = True
    # load from db
    # ...
    self.is_loading = False

# foo_callback is item_changed by example
def foo_callback(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
    if self.is_loading:
         return
    # do work
```

- Use blockSignals

```py
self.tablewidget.blockSignals(True)
# load from db
# ...
self.tablewidget.blockSignals(False)
```